# Tensorflow-Why is my ANN model not learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

here is my very basic ANN code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler,normalize

data = pd.read_csv("home_data.csv")
x = data.drop(['id', 'date', 'price'], axis=1).values
y = data['price'].values

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.33)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(18, input_shape=(18,), activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(36, input_shape=(18,), activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(18,), activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
r = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test,y_test), epochs=50)
plt.plot(r.history['loss'], label="loss")
plt.plot(r.history['val_loss'], label="val_loss")
plt.show()
```

However my loss is very high -around 426470263086- and never decreasing by time. Here is my loss graph
[image]

**UPDATE**

here is the some part of data I'm trying to deal with it.

```
           id             date     price  bedrooms  ...      lat     long  sqft_living15  sqft_lot15
0  7129300520  20141013T000000  221900.0         3  ...  47.5112 -122.257           1340        5650
1  6414100192  20141209T000000  538000.0         3  ...  47.7210 -122.319           1690        7639
2  5631500400  20150225T000000  180000.0         2  ...  47.7379 -122.233           2720        8062
3  2487200875  20141209T000000  604000.0         4  ...  47.5208 -122.393           1360        5000
4  1954400510  20150218T000000  510000.0         3  ...  47.6168 -122.045           1800        7503

[5 rows x 21 columns]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to predict continuous values. When predicting continuous values your activation in the final layer should be linear, or leaky relu (If predicting values are positive) else no activation.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler,normalize

data = pd.read_csv("home_data.csv")
x = data.drop(['id','price' ,'date'], axis=1).values
y = data['price'].values

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.33)

scaler = StandardScaler()
x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = scaler.transform(x_test)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_shape=(18,), activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(6, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="linear"))
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])
r = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test,y_test), epochs=10)

plt.plot(r.history['loss'], label="loss")
plt.plot(r.history['val_loss'], label="val_loss")
plt.show()
```

You don't have to specify input shape for hidden layers.

The computed loss of your model was very high because large variation of min and max values in the dataset.

After using standard scaler the loss was reduced.

Output:

```
Epoch 1/10
453/453 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 6093344963084377128960.0000 - root_mean_squared_error: 78059880448.0000 - val_loss: 9416156905472.0000 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 3068575.7500
Epoch 2/10
453/453 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 639826591744.0000 - root_mean_squared_error: 799891.6250 - val_loss: 155623915520.0000 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 394491.9688
Epoch 3/10
453/453 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 124726026240.0000 - root_mean_squared_error: 353165.7188 - val_loss: 155318534144.0000 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 394104.7188
Epoch 4/10
453/453 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 124705193984.0000 - root_mean_squared_error: 353136.2188 - val_loss: 155418017792.0000 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 394230.9062
Epoch 5/10
453/453 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 124720766976.0000 - root_mean_squared_error: 353158.2812 - val_loss: 155389984768.0000 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 394195.3750
Epoch 6/10
453/453 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 124696051712.0000 - root_mean_squared_error: 353123.2812 - val_loss: 155291697152.0000 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 394070.6875
Epoch 7/10
453/453 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 124681125888.0000 - root_mean_squared_error: 353102.1562 - val_loss: 155307376640.0000 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 394090.5625
Epoch 8/10
453/453 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 124710920192.0000 - root_mean_squared_error: 353144.3438 - val_loss: 155327266816.0000 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 394115.8125
Epoch 9/10
453/453 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 124708052992.0000 - root_mean_squared_error: 353140.2812 - val_loss: 155288338432.0000 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 394066.4062
Epoch 10/10
453/453 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 124725968896.0000 - root_mean_squared_error: 353165.6250 - val_loss: 155315683328.0000 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 394101.0938
```

Comment: I tried to run your code but it raises the error

Unknown metric function:root_mean_squared_error

Plus, my data is home price data so it must be discrete i suppose. It is not time depented or something. Just there are features of houses and prices of them.

Comment: House prices can take any value from 0 to infinity so they fall under continuous data  category. I have updated the code so I think this should work.

Comment: Ah thanks but still lost is very high, it is around 132903206961.7856 and constant... Never decreasing

Comment: Can you update your question to show some data that you are using to train the model?

Comment: I did now, added my kaggle source also

Comment: I have updated my answer. I have also added root_mean_squared_error as a metric. You can remove it it won't affect the code.

Comment: Still very very high loss and not decreasing... I'm desperate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220278/discussion-between-aniket-bote-and-m-utku).